# iOS 7 tabBar-line, how to remove it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Apple has added a tiny line over the tabBar in iOS 7 which is supposed to work as a shadow or fade between the tabBar and the UI

[image]

Since I am using a custom-made tabBar the line is quite irritating. How do you remove it?  Please tell me it is possible, otherwise I need to redesign my whole app lol....

/ Regards

***Edit**

*Sloved my problem with the following line of code:*

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: `[_tabBar setClipsToBounds:TRUE];`

Comment: holex answer worked like a miracle for me  ^_^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove UITabBar horizontal separator in iOS7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145216/remove-uitabbar-horizontal-separator-in-ios7)

Answer (score 22):

```
    UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tabbar_bg.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:tabBarBackground];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

Comment: Note: If you `setShadowImage`, it will occupy some spaces above the Tab Bar Controller. It's better to use `[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init];` to provide an empty and transparent `UIImage`.

Comment: @Raptor You are a genius.

Answer (score 14):

These code works pretty well for me (I don't really have background image for tab bar):

```
[tab_main.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

And I use these code to add a frame too:

```
UIColor* color_green = UIColorFromRGB(0x348e5b);
tab_main.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50;
tab_main.tabBar.layer.borderColor = color_green.CGColor;
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:color_green];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

In iOS 8 the top border can be removed by setting the tab bar style to black in the inspector.

Comment: Well it doesn't remove it, but make it white, I have a big center button and it cutting right though it

Answer (score 5):

**Swift**

*Nice simple solution:*

Write this below code in your custom tab bar class. Then it will hide horizontal shadow line.

```
self.tabBar.setValue(true, forKey: "_hidesShadow")
```

**Objective C**

```
[self.tabBar setValue:@(YES) forKeyPath:@"_hidesShadow"];
```

Comment: Private API is not preferred.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tabBarController =  [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGE.png"]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Comment: This code is confusing. The variable name is `tabBar` but you initialize `UITabBarController` on it.

Comment: My suggestion: rename the variable to `tabBarController` to avoid confusion

Comment: tabBar is object of UITabBarController.That means, @property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController* tabBar;I had edit the name tabBar to tabBarController(@property (nonatomic, retain) UITabBarController* tabBarController).Now you can understand the code without confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything in the `UITabBar` API for affecting that separator, but if the separator is within the UITabBar (a UIView subclass), I'd expect you can insert a new one-pixel-high UIView on top of it. You'd have to grab a slice of the image that you want to appear there and draw it in the new view. And I'm not sure if UITabBar would somehow prevent adding the subview or prevent the subview from being on top. But that's where I'd start.

Comment: Setting shadowImage to a clear image should get rid of it, provided that you also have a backgroundImage set

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in `AppDelegate.m` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=7.0)
 [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
UIImage* tabBarBackground = [UIImage new];
if(!OSVersionIsAtLeastiOS7())
{
    tabBarBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whitebg"];
}
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:tabBarBackground];

[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 [_tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tabtarsprnt"]]; //your custom image
[self.tabBarController.tabBar setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

this code also solved the my issue

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also needed to set a different shadow, in the end the only thing that worked while also setting a custom shadow was to add a single-point high UIView 1 point above the tab bar:

```
    UIView *whiteLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, -1.0, self.tabBar.frame.size.width, 1.0)];
    whiteLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.tabBar addSubview:whiteLine];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
** Objective-C **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: nil];

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage: [[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

** Swift **

```
//Remove shadow image by assigning nil value.
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = nil

// or 

// Assing UIImage instance without image reference
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

Here is apple document for [shadowImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623452-shadowimage).

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
open var shadowImage: UIImage?
```

> Default is nil. When non-nil, a custom shadow image to show instead of
>   the default shadow image. For a custom shadow to be shown, a custom
>   background image must also be set with -setBackgroundImage: (if the
>   default background image is used, the default shadow image will be
>   used).

Answer (score -1):

now you can use it, with this line:

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```